# Windows SSH keys on CentOS

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, centos

I have an internal CentOS 7 server which acts as a staging environment for our websites.

I, for the last year or so via SSH from a Linux Mint machine. Now, some other people are trying to get access to the server, so on their machines I

- installed Git bash
- used `ssh-keygen` (and spammed `enter`)
- used `ssh-copy-id user@dev.server.ip`

which returned:

> user@dev.server.ip: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

With that, I got them to send me their id_rsa.pub files, `cat`'ed them and then added them to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` and tried again, but the `ssh`/`sftp` commands return that same permission denied error.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, and like I said, it works for my (Linux) machine, but not their (Windows) machines.

I've set `PasswordAuthentication` to no in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and then restart the `sshd` service, but still no affect.

How can I get Windows SSH keys working on my Linux CentOS server?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you actually ssh by providing the `username` and `password`? If
>   not, then if you can access the file ensure you have an `AllowUsers`
>   entry in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and also that you are allowing SSH
>   access to the subnet at the top of that file. if you do amend the
>   `sshd_config` remember to restart the `SSH service`.

---

1. Check in `sshd_config` if you have:

---

```
AllowUsers

DenyGroups

DenyUsers
```

set and if you are allowed to access the remote.

---

2. Also it sometimes helps to reset this file `known_hosts` in then `$HOME/.ssh` directory:

---

```
cat /dev/null > $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
```

---

3. Check if `denyhosts` is installed and if it's blocked your `IP` address in the `hosts` file.

If you mange to blacklist your own IP address by attempting to log in via SSH with the wrong credentials multiple times, then you can connect to your service using the console (Connecting to your VPS using the console / VNC) and remove the block with following:

- Stop `denyhosts` service (`systemctl stop denyhosts` or `/etc/init.d/denyhosts stop`)
- Remove the line with the IP from /etc/hosts.deny
- Remove the lines with the IP from `/var/lib/denyhosts/hosts*` files (note: not all files will contain the IP)
- Remove the line with the IP from `/var/lib/denyhosts/user-hosts`
- Remove the lines on the `IPTABLES`’ table
- Start `denyhosts` service

---

4. Check if you got the right `port`

---

**If that's not the problem here are the step's to create key's and copy them to the remote:**

Create the key on the local system:

```
ssh-keygen -o -b 4096 -t rsa -C somethingSomething@mail.com
```

OR:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/vps-cloud.web-server.key -C "My web-server key"
```

You will be prompted to supply a passphrase (password) for your private key. I suggest that you setup a passphrase when prompted.

---

- -t rsa : Specifies the type of key to create. The possible values are “rsa1” for protocol version 1 and “dsa”, “ecdsa”, “ed25519”, or “rsa” for protocol version 2.
- -b 4096 : Specifies the number of bits in the key to create
- -f ~/.ssh/vps-cloud.web-server.key : Specifies the filename of the key file.
- -C "somethingSomething@mail.com" : Set a new comment.

If you want to be able to access the server from your root account, do `su` and repeat the above command.

1. `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`– contains your private key.
2. `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` – contains your public key.

Copy the key to remote:

```
ssh-copy-id USER@192.168.0.100
```

OR:

```
sh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@SERVER.com
```

OR:

First create `.ssh` directory on the remote server

```
ssh USER@SERVER.com "umask 077; test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh"
```

`cat` local id.`rsa.pub` file and pipe over ssh to append the public key in remote server

```
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USER@SERVER.COM "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

OR:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p 22000 USER@192.168.1.215 "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

If you want to be able to only enter your `key` passphrase once each session then add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

then you will be asked for the passphrase on terminal/shell start and not again.

Comment: 1) I don't need to use username + pass, as stated in my post, I can SSH in no problem, it's just Windows. 2) is a completely empty file.. 3) hosts.deny is completely empty ... 4) 100% correct port (copied from my .bashrc alias) 5) as stated, already done all of this..

Comment: can also confirm is Windows issue, just set up a new Linux user and it worked first time xD

Comment: @treyBake So it's fixed good for you, have a nice day :-)

Comment: no.. I just tested through Linux to see if it was a Windows thing